# Nuxt3 SSR multiple routes per file? Server Catch-all routes

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxt3

I'm working on a new app with SSR using Nuxt3, Vue3 and a Laravel backend. I'm wondering if there's a way to add multiple routes/api calls to one defineEventHandler function in each server/api file. Maybe that's not good practice? Here's what I have so far:

```
server/api/backend.js

    export default defineEventHandler(async (event) =>{

      const { rcn } = getQuery(event)

      const config = useRuntimeConfig()

      const uri  = `${config.apiBase}/api/${rcn}`
      const data = await $fetch(uri)
      return data
   })
```

I suppose I could do if/else statements based on what's in the `event.req.url` but that seems tedious. Again, if the proper way to set this up is a new file.js for each route then please let me know. It just seems like there should be a better way to group them all together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is the catch all routes([see documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#catch-all-route))

Usage:
`~/server/api/all-routes/[...].ts`

```js
import { createRouter, defineEventHandler, useBase } from 'h3';
const router = createRouter();

router.get(
  '/hello',
  defineEventHandler((event) => {
    return 'Hello from hello API';
  })
);
router.get(
  '/world',
  defineEventHandler((event) => {
    return 'World from World API';
  })
);

export default useBase('/api/all-routes/', router.handler);
```

#### Note:

ensure you have this on your catch all routes file. Otherwise, it won't work.

`export default useBase('/api/all-routes/', router.handler);`

`router.get('/api/')` - for GET method

`router.post('/api/')` - for POST method

And the other two for `update` & `delete`

Call the API on the client side.

```js
<script setup>
const { data: hello } = await useFetch('/api/all-routes/hello');
const { data: world } = await useFetch('/api/all-routes/world');
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      {{ hello }}
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ world }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

See working example
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-7we3jp?file=server/api/all-routes/[...].ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-7we3jp?file=server/api/all-routes/%5B...%5D.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. I saw the 'catch all' file in the docs but didn't think of using it in this way. You saved me a lot of time today :)

Comment: Glad to be of help, their documentation about the `catch all routes` is still incomplete. This link might be helpful for you 
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13696

Comment: Appreciate it! I'll check that out