# Nuxt3: /server directory structure. Dynamic Nested API routes

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3, nitro

In Nuxt3, I am using `useFetch` to call this url endpoint:

```
company = await useFetch(`/api/company/${companyKey}/profile`)
```

Notice the extra `/profile` at the end? How can I organize my `/server` directory to cater to a url endpoint of this structure?

For example: if the url had been without the `/profile` (i.e. `/api/company/${companyKey}`), then the `/server` directory would be simple to achieve:

```
/server/company/[companyKey].get.js
```

However, with the extra `/profile` appended at the end, it becomes more tricky to think about.

How can I handle this scenario? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they call this a nested dynamic server API routes.

I created an example for you based on your question. Tested and it works.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-wv9cuk?file=app.vue

*Edit*

```js
/* 
* Folder structure would be
 - server
   - api - FOLDER
    - company - FOLDER
     - [company_key] - FOLDER
      - profile.get.ts - FILE
*    - [company_kuy].get.ts - FILE
*/
```

#### Alternative

You can also use the catch-all-route. See link example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76151522/21341655